# No PSpiceTemplate warning in PSpice

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, simulation, spice, pspice

I am trying to simulate the following circuit in PSpice, but I face the this warning in base of the transistor. changing the transistor didn't solve this issue. Please help me fixing it!

WARNING:  [NET0093]
No PSpiceTemplate for Q3, ignoring

ERROR -- Less than 2 connections at node N00711
ERROR -- Node N00740 is floating
ERROR -- Node N00711 is floating
ERROR -- Node GND is floating

[image]

Comment: I don't see a `Q2` in there. Have you verified all your connections? Click on each element and move them around, are there wires that remain floating?

Comment: Because I changed the transistor, this happened. I edited the question. The updated warning concerns about Q3.

Comment: It looks like it has no model or subcircuit attached to the symbol. I don't have PSpice, but IIRC, there are libraries for PCB and for SPICE; which one did you choose from? Did you verify all your connections? BTW, if this is about simulating a speaker as a load then your load does not look like the one suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Can you include the Spice netlist?  It may be that you are missing a connection or the transistor does not have a model attached